# Select data attributes and add them in input elements in plain js

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a simple User Information form. In my form i have a **select** element with four **options** inside it. The options have four **data** **attributes** with some information for the users. Below my **select** i have four **input** types that will represent one of the **data** **attribute** that i have on my **select**. What I would like to happen is when i select each of the user to get the **data** **attributes** and fill in the **input** elements. Anyone know how can I achieve that? I would like it in plain JS. I have tried using onchange event but no luck. Can someone provide me with the JS code? I will add many users so if someone can help me with the code using (this) instead of selecting users with id i would appreciate it.

Thanks.

HTML:

```
<form id="usersInfo" action="#" method="post" onsubmit="return false">

        <label>User Information</label>
        <select id="firstSelect" onchange="usersFunction()">
            <option value="10" data-name="Name One" data-surname="Surname One" data-email="Email One" data-country="Country One">User One</option>
            <option value="20" data-name="Name Two" data-surname="Surname Two" data-email="Email Two" data-country="Country Two">User Two</option>
            <option value="30" data-name="Name Three" data-surname="Surname Three" data-email="Email Three" data-country="Country Three">User Three</option>
            <option value="40" data-name="Name Four" data-surname="Surname Four" data-email="Email Four" data-country="Country Four">User Four</option>
        </select>

        <input type="text" id="userName" placeholder="User Name">
        <input type="text" id="userSurname" placeholder="User Surname">
        <input type="text" id="userEmail" placeholder="User Email">
        <input type="text" id="userCountry" placeholder="User Country">

    </form>
```

Javascript

```
function usersFunction() {
    var x = document.querySelector("#firstSelect");

    var dataName = x.getAttribute("data-name");
    var dataSurname = x.getAttribute("data-surname");
    var dataEmail = x.getAttribute("data-email");
    var dataCountry = x.getAttribute("data-country");

    var userName = document.querySelector("#userName");
    var userSurname = document.querySelector("#userSurname");
    var userEmail = document.querySelector("#userEmail");
    var userCountry = document.querySelector("#userCountry");

    userName.value = dataName;
    userSurname.value = dataSurname;
    userEmail.value = dataEmail;
    userCountry.value = dataCountry;

}
```

Comment: @T.J Crowder ok i have edited my question and i have also included my JS code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to read the `data-*` attributes from the `select` element, but they're on the *option* element. You need to find the option element and then read the `data-*` attributes from there. You're doing everything else right, though there's a tweak I'd suggest which I'll describe below.

To find the selected option, get the options within the select and then look for the one whose `selected` property is `true`:

```
var options = document.querySelectorAll("#firstSelect option");
var selected;
var n;
for (n = 0; !selected && n < options.length; ++n) {
    if (options[n].selected) {
        selected = options[n];
    }
}
if (!selected) {
    return; // None selected -- or you might choose to use the first one in this case
}
var dataName = selected.getAttribute("data-name");
var dataSurname = selected.getAttribute("data-surname");
var dataEmail = selected.getAttribute("data-email");
var dataCountry = selected.getAttribute("data-country");
```

Live example:

```js
function usersFunction() {
  var options = document.querySelectorAll("#firstSelect option");
  var selected;
  var n;
  for (n = 0; !selected && n < options.length; ++n) {
    if (options[n].selected) {
      selected = options[n];
    }
  }
  if (!selected) {
    return; // None selected -- or you might choose to use the first one in this case
  }
  var dataName = selected.getAttribute("data-name");
  var dataSurname = selected.getAttribute("data-surname");
  var dataEmail = selected.getAttribute("data-email");
  var dataCountry = selected.getAttribute("data-country");

  var userName = document.querySelector("#userName");
  var userSurname = document.querySelector("#userSurname");
  var userEmail = document.querySelector("#userEmail");
  var userCountry = document.querySelector("#userCountry");

  userName.value = dataName;
  userSurname.value = dataSurname;
  userEmail.value = dataEmail;
  userCountry.value = dataCountry;

}
```

```html
<form id="usersInfo" action="#" method="post" onsubmit="return false">

  <label>User Information</label>
  <select id="firstSelect" onchange="usersFunction()">
    <option value="10" data-name="Name One" data-surname="Surname One" data-email="Email One" data-country="Country One">User One</option>
    <option value="20" data-name="Name Two" data-surname="Surname Two" data-email="Email Two" data-country="Country Two">User Two</option>
    <option value="30" data-name="Name Three" data-surname="Surname Three" data-email="Email Three" data-country="Country Three">User Three</option>
    <option value="40" data-name="Name Four" data-surname="Surname Four" data-email="Email Four" data-country="Country Four">User Four</option>
  </select>

  <input type="text" id="userName" placeholder="User Name">
  <input type="text" id="userSurname" placeholder="User Surname">
  <input type="text" id="userEmail" placeholder="User Email">
  <input type="text" id="userCountry" placeholder="User Country">

</form>
```

Note that since a drop-down select with no initially-selected option is shown as though the first option is selected, you might want to default to the first option if you don't find any by replacing that `if` with the comment above with:

```
selected = selected || option[0];
```

And if you did that, you might run the function on page load so that the first option's information is automatically filled in the fields.

---

Side note: When you're *just* looking something up by its ID, you can use `document.getElementById("id")` rather that `document.querySelector("#id")`.